# Future of APK files

Tags: android, apk, future

Does Google plan to phase out APK files completely? Currently I allow users to download a copy of my APK file from my website, but am worried that this might not always be possible. They are already being phased out in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Google has introduced app bundles to reduce size of application. In this way a user can only have to download the bundle, according to his device's need. But APK generation cannot be phase out because it is open source for app gallery and some other platforms as well as local server which manages their APKs internally. So dont worry about it.

Comment: Someone has voted down both my question and your answer, without giving a reason. I am voting up your answer to compensate.